# find_or_initialize block is not running in service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a service object designed to build or edit contact objects:

```
class BuildOrEditContact
    include Service
    def self.call(employee_json, company_id)
        Contact.find_or_initialize_by(uid: employee_json['uid'] || employee_json['uuid']) do |c|
                c.name = employee_json['name']
                puts "Creating/updating #{c.name}."
                c.email = employee_json['email']
                c.job_title = employee_json['title']
                c.bio = employee_json['bio']
                c.phone = employee_json['phone']
                c.avatar_url = employee_json['avatar_url']
                c.company_id = company_id
                c.save
                puts "Saving #{c.name}, the #{c.job_title} of #{company_json['name']}"
            end
    end
end
```

It was running fine, until I added the company_id and job_title lines.

Now, when I run the code with a binding.pry before the find_or_initialize by call, it stops and I can run the code line-by-line.

Individually, the lines work fine. As a block, it's a no-go.

When I copy and paste the whole block into pry, it runs everything except for the job_title and company_id lines.

If I put binding.pry inside the block (above `c.name = employee_json['name']`) it never stops. The code just runs as if I made no changes (no job_title, company_id, or puts)

What is causing this selective malfunction?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So this fixed it:

I removed the block and used find_or_initialize_by as you'd normally see it:

```
class BuildOrEditContact
    include Service
    def self.call(employee_json, company_id)
        c = Contact.find_or_initialize_by(uid: employee_json['uid'] || employee_json['uuid'])
        c.name = employee_json['name']
        puts "Creating/updating #{c.name}."
        c.email = employee_json['email']
        c.job_title = employee_json['title']
        c.bio = employee_json['bio']
        c.phone = employee_json['phone']
        c.avatar_url = employee_json['avatar_url']
        c.company_id = company_id
        c.save
        puts "Saving #{c.name}, the #{c.job_title} of #{c.company.name}"
    end
end
```